# How to add Button which will go to the correspond mail to verify email

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, firebase

How to add Button to verify email.I have used a button and used firebase to impliment login and signup.If user doesn't verify email i want add a button which will go to the perspective email (like gmail, yahoo etc if the user email is gmail or yahoo he will go to gmail or yahoo only) to verify.How could i  add that link to my button. [image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5bHl.png) [image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NPmP.jpg)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

After implementing the button you can use a call back function on onClick. Clicking that button a function will be called. In that function you can use the firebase sendEmailVerification function.

```
    const [sendEmailVerification, sending, error] = useSendEmailVerification(auth);
const sendEmail = async () => {
  await sendEmailVerification();
}
<button onClick={() => sendEmail()}>Send Email Verification</>
```

Comment: did you read the question? "" want add a button which will go to the perspective email (like gmail, yahoo etc if the user email is gmail or yahoo he will go to gmail or yahoo only) to verify.How could i add that link to my button"